# Show contents of a folder Objective-C

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, macos

I  want to show the music files in a folder in Objective-C in a window so the user can see it.

It will always be the same folder, so I don't need to be able to browse.

I've tried NSBrowser, but the Apple SimpleCocoaBrowser example wasn't that simple, and did much more than I needed it to.

What would be the best way to do this? NSTableView?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

With this code, you get an array with all pdf's on the Desktop of the user named "Thomas". You can change the file extension to mp3 or something else.
With an array controller you are able to fill this information into a tableview.

```
NSError *error = nil;

NSArray *desktopFiles = [[NSFileManager defaultManager] contentsOfDirectoryAtPath:@"/Users/Thomas/Desktop" error:&error];

if(desktopFiles == nil){
   NSLog(@"%@", [error localizedDescription]);
   return 0;
}

NSArray *filteredDesktopFiles = [desktopFiles filteredArrayUsingPredicate:[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"self ENDSWITH '.pdf'"]];

for (id filename in filteredDesktopFiles){
    NSLog (@"Filename: %@", filename);
}
```

Comment: You've hardcoded the path to Desktop; you're using string paths instead of NSURLs, you're checking the error parameter before checking the return value from a method; the array sounds like it contains jpg files not PDF files.

Comment: I hardcovered the path because Miniroo only needs a hardcoded path. In my opinion it's better the check the error before some other code is running. Isn't it? With the varible names you are completly right. I will change this.

Comment: When you have a method that takes an error parameter, you should check that the return from the method is not nil before checking the parameter. It's only when the return from the method is nil that the error parameter contains a valid error. See the [this documentation page](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/ErrorHandlingCocoa/CreateCustomizeNSError/CreateCustomizeNSError.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40001806-CH204-BAJIIGCC) look at the information box after listing 2-1 which backs this up.

Comment: OK. Thank you for this hint. Is it better now or did I misunderstand the documentation page?